# ¿es estrictamente necesario devolver un throw para poder propagar el error en un try catch?

Tags: nodejs, express, try-catch, async-await

Tal vez el título no sea muy explícito, por eso voy a tratar de explicar lo mejor posible. Estoy trabajando con Angular y Node.js con Express y tengo este código:

El manejador de rutas:

```js
router.post('/resendLink', async (req, res) => {
    console.log('\nMostrando valor de email:'+req.body.email)
    try {
        console.log('\nEntrando a resendLink... \n')
        let result = await Users.resendLink(req.body.email)
        console.log('\n\nEste msj se muestra despues de resolver Users.resendLink\n\n');
        if(result.emailFound===false)
            res.status(403).json(result);
        else{
            console.log('\nenviando status 200 en resendLink\n')
            res.status(200).json(result);
        }
    } catch(err) {
        console.log('\n**** Ocurrió un error en Routes Resend Link\n,err');
        res.status(500).json({error: err.message});
    }

})
```

y este es el modelo:

```js
const resendLink = async ( email ) => {
        try{
            const userRow = await getByEmail(email);
            if(userRow[0]){ // si el correo se encuentra registrado
                //console.log('Entró al If')
                const accountRow = await getByIdCuenta(userRow[0].id_usuario);
                if(accountRow[0]){
                    const salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync(); 
                    const hash = bcrypt.hashSync(userRow[0].nombres+userRow[0].id_usuario,salt);
                    let msj= '<h3> Te has registrado en LogoMarca. </h3> Solo un último paso... haz click en el siguiente link para activar tu cuenta:<br>'
                    let link= 'http://localhost:4200/activateAccount/?hash='+hash+'&id='+accountRow[0].id_cuenta;
                    let subject = 'LogoMarca - Verifica tu cuenta';
                    const resultEmail = await emailConfig({link: link, msj: msj, nameLink: 'activa tu cuenta',subject: subject});
                    return {emailFound: true, msj: 'the link was sent successfully'}
                }
            }else{
                return {emailFound: false, msj: 'the email does not exist'}
            }
        }catch(err){
            console.log('\nHa ocurrido un error en resendLink',err)
            return err;
        }
};
```

Estoy haciendo pruebas para ver si se captura y se muestran corrrectamente los errores pero tengo problemas, por ejemplo: si emailConfig el cuál es una Promise me devuelve un error éste si se muestra en el catch del modelo, pero no se propaga al catch del manejador de rutas a pesar de que lo retorno en el catch con `return err`, en el manejador de rutas siempre me está entrando al else donde respondo con: `res.status(200).json(result);` . Estuve probando y la única forma en que se propaga el error al manejador de rutas es si retorno una excepción en el modelo así:

```js
        }catch(err){
            console.log('\nHa ocurrido un error en resendLink',err)
            throw err;
        }
```

De esa forma si se propaga el error al manejador de la ruta, y ahí si me entra al catch de dicho manejador y se ejecuta la línea:

```js
    } catch(err) {
        console.log('\n**** Ocurrió un error en Routes Resend Link\n,err');
        res.status(500).json({error: err.message});
    }
```

Entonces, para poder retornar el error al manejador de rutas es estrictamente necesario que retorne una excepción?

Por qué si retorno el error no funciona?

---- Otro problema que se me presentó es el siguiente:

tengo esta función asíncrona:

```js
const saveRefreshToken= async (id_cuenta)=> {
    try {
        console.log('\nEjecutando getUserRowByAccountId...\n')
        const userRow = await getUserRowByAccountId(id_cuenta)
        console.log('Mostrando resultado de getUserRowByAccountId',userRow[0]);
        if(userRow[0]){
            let infoToken= createToken(userRow[0].id_usuario);
            console.log('\nEjecutando update de refreshToken...\n');
            bd.query('UPDATE usuario set refreshToken= ? where id_usuario= ?', [infoToken.refreshToken,userRow[0].id_usuario], (err,rows) =>{
                if(err){
                    console.log('\nEjecutando throw en saveRefreshToken...\n')
                    throw err;
                }
                else{
                    console.log('entrando al else en saveRefreshToken');
                    return  {updateToken: true, token: infoToken.token, refreshToken: infoToken.refreshToken}
                }
            })
        }else{
            return {updateToken: false}
        }
    } catch(e) {
        throw e;
    }

}
```

y la estoy tratando de resolver acá:

```js
                Users.saveRefreshToken(req.body.id)
                    .then( result => {
                        console.log('\nimprimiendo result: '+result);
                        if(result.updateToken){
                            console.log('se inserto el refreshToken en la BD con saveRefreshToken')
                            //console.log(`\nSI existe rows en activateAccount`,rows[0]);
                            res.status(200).json(infoToken);
                        }else{
                            console.log('entrando a error 500 en activeAccount')
                            //console.log(`\nNO existe rows en activateAccount`,rows[0]);
                            res.status(500).json({userFound: false}); //no existe el id en la BD
                        }
                    })
                    .catch(err => { console.log(err) })
```

Y el problema es que me está diciendo que la propiedad updateToken no está definida, lo que parece estar sucediendo es que se está ejecutando esa línea sin haber resuelto la promesa (Users.saveRefreshToken) antes. si al colocar el async en la función eso me devuelve una promesa,como es que no se está ejecutando como esperaba? estoy un poco confundido acá también.

Comment: Te recomiendo escribir otra pregunta, ya que la edición que haces no tiene nada que ver con la pregunta original, es un problema diferente. Saludos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La documentación para la sentencia [`return`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/return) y para la sentencia [`throw`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/throw) nos dan luces al respecto.

Una sentencia `return` finaliza la ejecución de un método o función devolviendo un valor (si no se especifica un valor, se devuelve `undefined`). Por lo tanto, se entiende que la función finalizó correctamente.

Un sentencia `throw` por el contrario, *lanza* un error definido por el usuario. Lo cual le indica al motor de JS que ha ocurrido un problema. El error es propagado hasta el siguiente bloque `catch` en la pila, si no hubiera un bloque en la pila, el programa se detiene.

En cuanto a tu pregunta, *¿es necesario usar una sentencia `throw`?* pues eso dependerá de tu lógica. Lo que si es necesario es manejar correctamente las Promesas, para no vernos en situaciones inesperadas.

Tienes una función tipo `async` llamada `resendLink`. Toda función tipo `async` devuelve una Promesa. Por lo tanto, para usarla correctamente con `await` debes hacerlo dentro de un bloque `try / catch`. Si no la usas en un contexto de función `async` entonces debes usar los métodos `then()` y `catch()`.

Dentro de tu función `resendLink` usas también un proceso asíncrono que devuelve una Promesa, la cual correctamente encierras dentro de un bloque `try / catch`.

Vista la documentación, si deseo que el bloque `catch` superior (externo) capture el posible error que devuelva mi Promesa interna, debo usar una sentencia `throw` en mi bloque `catch` interno, ya que si uso una sentencia `return` estoy indicando que la función ha finalizado sin contratiempos, cosa que es falso.

Lo que queda claro de todo esto, y de acuerdo a la lógica planteada en tu pregunta, la única forma de capturar el error usando un bloque `catch` fuera de tu función `async` llamada `resendLink` es mediante el uso de `throw`.

Alguien podría decirte que no uses un bloque `try / catch` dentro del método `resendLink`, pero eso no es una buena práctica de cara al manejo de Promesas.

Comment: Entonces quiere decir que yo al hacer un `return (err)`, estría haciendo como un ``` resolve (err) ```  ? Se me presentó otro problema relacionado con esta pregunta, la edité para ver si me podrías hacer una aclaratoria al respecto. Gracias de antemano.